# error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'inRange' > Overload resolution failed: > - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, opencv, streamlit

So I have this Streamlit code below, I'm approaching to detect certain color desired by user where the user needed to insert the hsv range color, so I did that by taking each of the lower and upper range value inputs and then assigns it as `np.array` and apply a mask to the image based on the user HSV input value, code:

```
def load_img(img_file):
    img = Image.open(img_file)
    return img

def detection():
    get_img = st.file_uploader('Upload An Image',type=['png','jpg','jpeg'])
    select_det = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select Detection Category',
                                      ['Color Detection',
                                      'Eye Pupil Detection',
                                      'Edge Detection',
                                      'Car Detection'])
    if select_det == "Color Detection":
        if get_img is not None:
            st.image(load_img(get_img))
            option_form = st.sidebar.form('options_form')
            lower0 = int(option_form.number_input('Lower Range Value 1'))
            lower1 = int(option_form.number_input('Lower Range Value 2'))
            lower2 = int(option_form.number_input('Lower Range Value 3'))
            detect = option_form.form_submit_button('Apply')

            option_form1 = st.sidebar.form('options_form1')
            upper0 = int(option_form1.number_input('Upper Range Value 1'))
            upper1 = int(option_form1.number_input('Upper Range Value 2'))
            upper2 = int(option_form1.number_input('Upper Range Value 3'))
            detect1 = option_form1.form_submit_button('Apply')

            if detect or detect1:
                lower_val = np.array([lower0,lower1,lower2],dtype=np.uint8)
                upper_val = np.array([upper0,upper1,upper2],dtype=np.uint8)
                mask = cv2.inRange(get_img,lower_val,upper_val)
                result = cv2.bitwise_and(get_img,get_img,mask=mask)                

                st.subheader(lower_val)
                st.subheader(upper_val)
```

Turned out I got this error on my streamlit website:

```
error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'inRange' > Overload resolution failed: > - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar > - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

Full traceback:

```
  Traceback:
    File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 554, in _run_script
        exec(code, module.__dict__)
    File "oneml.py", line 208, in <module>
        main()
    File "oneml.py", line 206, in main
        detection()
    File "oneml.py", line 190, in detection
        mask = cv2.inRange(get_img,lower_val,upper_val)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problems:**

According to [this documentation from Streamlit](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.file_uploader), `file_uploader` allows you to choose a file and gives the corresponding file name in return. In your case, the variable `get_img` contains an image file name. This is **not** what you should be passing into `cv2.inRange`. `cv2.inRange` expects an array, just like the error message says.

The next line `st.image(load_img(get_img))` only shows the image, you have not stored it in a variable. The image must be stored as an array in a variable to be used later.

**Solution:**

You already have a function in place to load an image. Assign the result to a variable like:

```
image = load_img(get_img)
```

`image` contains the image you uploaded as an array. Now pass it as input to `cv2.inRange`:

```
mask = cv2.inRange(image,lower_val,upper_val)
```

Comment: Same as cv2.bitwise_and too.

Comment: Ok I followed your solution and thanksfully the error is gone but now I encountered with similar error: *error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'inRange' > Overload resolution failed: > - src data type = 17 is not supported > - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'*

Comment: @PythonicUser Please update the code changes you made in your question

Comment: @Jeru Luke Ok nevermind that, the error is now fixed thanks for your help

Comment: @PythonicUser Where was the issue? And how did you fix it?